# QCompleter show all items PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

I create an application with QCompleter.  I would like to show all items from completer when the QLineEdit is empty. But i dont know how to do it. I found a C++ code with a similiar question but i need to do it on Python.

```
if(lineEdit->text().isEmpty())
    {
      lineEdit->completer()->setCompletionPrefix("");
      lineEdit->completer()->complete();
    }
```

Method `setCompletionPrefix` does not work in Python

Please help me solve this task on Python

Python 3.6.8, PyQT5 5.15.4

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please provide a proper [mcve] that shows what you actually tried.